# Convert human readable string to TimeSpan

Tags: c#, regex

I want to pass time interval as a string (to program args) and then I want to parse it to `TimeSpan`. I created simple class:

```
public static class TimeSpanConverter
    {
        public static TimeSpan Convert(string input)
        {
            var units = new Dictionary<string, int>()
            {
                {@"(\d+)(ms|mili[|s]|milisecon[|s])", 1 },
                {@"(\d+)(s|sec|second[|s])", 1000 },
                {@"(\d+)(m|min[|s])", 60000 },
                {@"(\d+)(h|hour[|s])", 3600000 },
                {@"(\d+)(d|day[|s])", 86400000 },
                {@"(\d+)(w|week[|s])", 604800000 },
            };

            var timespan = new TimeSpan();

            foreach(var x in units)
            {
                var matches = Regex.Matches(input, x.Key);
                foreach(Match match in matches)
                {
                    var amount = System.Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[1].Value);
                    timespan = timespan.Add(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(x.Value * amount));
                }
            }

            return timespan;
        }
    }
```

Which is working, and I can easly parse like this:

```
var interval = TimeSpanConverter.Convert("1day13hour2min12s52ms");
```

What do you think about that? How can I improve that? I have a feeling, that it is not well coded.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ```
> public static class TimeSpanConverter
>     {
>         public static TimeSpan Convert(string input)
> ```

To people who use WPF a lot, the name hints at this class being a `TypeConverter` or an `IValueConverter`. I would say that it's really a parser. Similarly, I think that the method should be called `Parse`.

---

> ```
>             var units = new Dictionary<string, int>()
>             {
>                 {@"(\d+)(ms|mili[|s]|milisecon[|s])", 1 },
>                 {@"(\d+)(s|sec|second[|s])", 1000 },
>                 {@"(\d+)(m|min[|s])", 60000 },
>                 {@"(\d+)(h|hour[|s])", 3600000 },
>                 {@"(\d+)(d|day[|s])", 86400000 },
>                 {@"(\d+)(w|week[|s])", 604800000 },
>             };
> ```

The prefix *milli* has two *l*s. *millisecond* ends in a *d*.

`[|s]` is more idiomatically written as `s?`.

Given the way the regexes are used (searching for matches without anchoring), most of them could be simplified. E.g. any match for `min` would also match `m`, so `@"(\d+)m"` will find exactly the same multiples of a minute.

The numbers on the right are *magic numbers*, and at a glance I can't be completely certain that they're correct. I would prefer to use `TimeSpan` instances and take advantage of `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1)`, `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)`, etc.

I think that a real world example of a human-readable string would be `"1 day, 13 hours, 2 minutes, 12 seconds, and 52 ms"`. At the very least, I would add `\s*` between the digits and the units.

Another quite realistic example would be `"2 minutes and 13.5 seconds"`.

It's also plausible that people will use `:` as a separator: `"2 days, 11:04:20"`

Then you get ugly stuff like months and years, which don't have fixed lengths.

If you want to refuse to parse some of these, that's fine. But in that case, I think the method still needs to handle them by throwing an exception. At present they would all return `TimeSpan.Zero`, which is misleading.

Have you given any thought to localisation? If you only want to use this in an English-language context, wouldn't `[0-9]` make more sense than `\d`? If you're matching all digits, you should have test cases for things like `"¹day١hourminute①second"`.

---

> ```
>             var timespan = new TimeSpan();
> ```

Can you think of a more descriptive name for this variable?

---

> ```
>                 var matches = Regex.Matches(input, x.Key);
>                 foreach(Match match in matches)
> ```

If the string has more than one match for a given regex, isn't that rather worrying? I wouldn't consider `"4hours2minutes1hour"` to be a very realistic input.

---

> ```
>                     var amount = System.Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[1].Value);
>                     timespan = timespan.Add(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(x.Value * amount));
> ```

Again, `amount` isn't a very descriptive name.

`TimeSpan` supports the operator `+`, and IMO `total += addend;` is more readable than `total = total.Add(addend);`.

Comment: _I would add \s* between the digits and the units._ - In such cases I usually _normalize_ a string first by replacing all multiple-whitespaces by a single one to avoid using the `*`.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to Peter Taylors answer:

> `@"(\d+)(ms|mili[|s]|milisecon[|s])"`
>
> `@"(\d+)(m|min[|s])"`

`"5ms"` will be caught by both patterns above.

---

> `var amount = System.Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[1].Value);`

For `weeks > 3` this will make an overflow when multiplied with `604800000`.

You should use `double.Parse()`, because `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds()` takes a double as argument.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have experience in programming in C#, but I do have some regex advice to share.

You can DRY your pattern by

```
(\d+)(?:ms|mili(?:secon)?s?)
(\d+)(?:s(?:ec)?|seconds?)
(\d+)(?:m|mins?)
(\d+)(?:h|hours?)
(\d+)(?:d|days?)
(\d+)(?:w|weeks?)
```

I am encouraging:

- non-capturing groups when there is no use for the matched substrings.
- I am using the zero or more quantifier (`?`) to reduce repetition and alternation (pipes).
- the omission of pipes in your character classes because they are useless in your expected input.
- `s?` to make pluralization optional.

If you need to ensure that `m` is not followed by `s` when executing the minutes pattern, you will need to extend the pattern. Perhap `m(?!s)|mins?`.

If you are in control of the incoming strings, please correct the spelling of `milliseconds`